# Obtain string from JSON Object

Tags: android, json

I have to following response from a server: `page:{"result":"ok","id_photo":36782710}`.And I'm trying to obtain the `result` from there by doing this:

```
String r=page.toString();
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(r);
JSONObject jsdata = r.getJSONObject(0);

String result = jsdata.getString("result");
System.out.println("Raspunsul de la server este:" +result);
```

But I get the following error:

```
WARN/System.err(30452): org.json.JSONException: Value {"result":"ok","id_photo":36782710} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
at com.Contest.DialogExampleActivity.executeMultiPartPost(DialogExampleActivity.java:131)
at com.Contest.DialogExampleActivity.btnSend_onClick(DialogExampleActivity.java:88)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2157)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2534)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9210)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method
```

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try instantiating it as a JSONObject instead as the data your a parsing is not an array but a object.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
String result = json.getString("result");
```

Answer (score 2):

As madsleejensen said, it should be treated as `JSONObject` not `JSONArray`, and for future references, simple advice to differ when to use the right type is: `JSONObject` is covered by `{}` and `JSONArray` covered by `[]`.

Comment: +1 Thanks so much for adding this bit of information.  I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out what the problem was.  Once I switched to JSONArray - it worked!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/